# Angularjs Filter not filtering for exact match

Tags: angularjs, filter, angular-filters

The below code throws alert match when I compare **abcd** with **abcd**,and alert **mismatch**  when I compare **abcd** with abdc .The weird thing is when I compare **abcd** with **abc**, it shows **match** instead of **mismatch**. 
What am i doing wrong. My problem statement is to compare whetherthe entered code is present in the list.

```
var enteredCode=$scope.enteredCode;
      var code= $filter('filter')( $scope.codeList, enteredCode);
      if(code.length>0){
         alert("element present");
      } else{ 
         alert("element not present"); 
      }
```

Please let me know what wrong am i doing.

Comment: The code is incorrect. Are you missing the closing ) in your alerts in your code or was this a pasting error?

Comment: @JaredReeves where do you say that the OP is missing a a closing parenthesis? I can't see any incorrect syntax in that code.

Comment: in the alerts they are both alert("something"

Comment: I was going to edit the code but was not sure if it was a pasting error or it is in the OP source code

Comment: @JaredReeves I thought that you were saying that there was a missing parenthesis in the $filter function, my bad!

Comment: @JaredReeves I see, no, after reading the question I think that it's quite clear that the OP issue is that they are expecting to get results for the exact matches only. Thanks for pointing that out!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In order to obtain only the exact matches you should set the [`comparator`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/filter) parameter of the `$filter filter` to `true`, like this:

```
var code= $filter('filter')( $scope.codeList, enteredCode, true);
```

### [Example](http://jsfiddle.net/cm851zaz/1/)

Comment: @user2375298 no problem, take your time, but you can also try it in the example of the question ;)